# After appending new row via jquery. The select2 of appended row wont work

Tags: jquery, laravel

My app.js initialize all of my select tags into select2.

But Im having problems on the appended row (class="entry-row") via js. When i click the select of the appended row it wont show any dropdown there's no event. The first-entry works fine since the select2 already initialize.

app.js

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    //Initialize Select2 Elements
    $('select').select2();
});
```

In my index.blade.php has something like this

```
<div class="form-group center-block">
    <h5 class="cte-title">My Title</h5>
</div>
<div class="transfer-copy-table-container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12 no-padding">
            <table class="table table-hover" width="100%" id="transfer-copy-table">
                <thead style="text-align: center">
                <tr class="row-header"><th>Courier</th><th>Location</th></tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="entry-body">
                <tr id="first-entry" class="entry-row">
                    <td>
                        <select name="data[source_role][]"  class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select Courier</option>
                            @foreach($couriers as $courier)
                                <option value="{{ $courier->courier }}">{{ $courier->courier ? $courier->courier : ''}} {{ $courier->courier }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="data[source_team][]"  class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Select Location</option>
                            @foreach($locations as $location)
                                <option value="{{ $location->location }}">{{ $location->location ? $location->location : ''}} {{ $location->location }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td style="text-align: center" class="btn-column">
                        <button class="remove-row btn btn-danger" title="remove"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr><td colspan="5" style="border-right: none"></td><td style="border-left: none" class="align-right"><button id="add-row" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Row</button></td></tr>
                </tfoot>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var first_tr = $('#first-entry').html();
    });

    $('#add-row').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('tbody#entry-body').append('<tr class="entry-row">' +first_tr + '</tr>');
    });
</script>
```

I tried fixing it by re-initializing the select2 but it creates another select2 container outside my existing select2 container and still not working

```
$('#add-row').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('tbody#entry-body').append('<tr class="entry-row">' +first_tr + '</tr>');
   $('tbody#entry-body tr.entry-row:last select').select2(); <---- Added Line
});
```

Comment: Hi, check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/crmgLv6j/) works for you .